# In SPSS, can I raise an exception inside a BEGIN PROGRAM-END PROGRAM block which interrupts SPSS code?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, spss

I have some SPSS syntax which occasionally incorporates python code inside BEGIN PROGRAM-END PROGRAM blocks, like so:

```
RENAME VARIABLES example_variable = renamed_example_variable
...
...
BEGIN PROGRAM.
    if condition:
        run_code()
    else:
        raise Exception("Exception occurred")
END PROGRAM.
...
...
RECODE X (0 = 1) (1 = 2).
EXECUTE.
```

After an exception is raised within the BEGIN PROGRAM-END PROGRAM block, is there a way to use this exception to interrupt SPSS, so that it will not run the syntax that follows it (i.e. RECODE ...)?

Comment: Another way to put it is that I'm looking for a "conditional breakpoint" - something that acts like a breakpoint in SPSS syntax, but only when an error is thrown inside the python programmability block.